# How to extract some words pattern from string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I want to extract words from a string that contain specific character (/IN) until to other specific character (/NNP). My code so far (still not work):

```
import re

sentence = "Entah/RB kenapa/NN ini/DT bayik/NN suka/VBI banget/JJ :/: )/CP :/: )/CP :/: )/CP berenang/VBI di/IN Jln/NN Terusan/NNP Borobudur/NNP dan/NN di/IN Jalan/NN Perempatan/ADJ Malioboro/NNP"

tes = re.findall(r'((?:\S+/IN\s\w+/NNP\s*)+)', sentence)
print(tes)
```

So the `sentence` contain words `di/IN Jln/NN Terusan/NNP Borobudur/NNP` and `di/IN Jalan/NN Perempatan/ADJ Malioboro/NNP` that I like to extract. The expected result:

```
['di/IN Jln/NN Terusan/NNP Borobudur/NNP', 'di/IN Jalan/NN Perempatan/ADJ Malioboro/NNP']
```

What is the best way to do this task? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
r'\S+/IN\b(?:(?!\S+/IN\b).)+\S+/NNP\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S7PyAs/5)

**Details**

- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `/IN\b` - a `/IN` substring as a whole word
- `(?:(?!\S+/IN\b).)+` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars that do not match the `\S+/IN\b` pattern sequence (use `re.DOTALL` to match line breaks, too)
- `\S+/NNP\b` - 1+ non-whitespaces, `/NNP` as a whole word (since `\b` is a word boundary)

Comment: Try : `sentence = "Entah/RB kenapa/NN ini/DT bayik/NN suka/VBI banget/JJ :/: )/CP :/: )/CP :/: )/CP berenang/VBI di/IN Jln/NN Terusan/NNP Borobudur d/NN /NNP dan/NN di/IN Jalan/NN Perempatan/ADJ Malioboro/NNP"` added `d/NN` between the first two `NNP`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Beside that case it also doesn't cover the case that there is no string between `/IN` and  `/NNp`.

Comment: @Kasramvd: There must be something between them, there will be at least a space, thus the `+` quantifier is correct.

Comment: I mean with space. It doesn't match that case. Test with `sentence = "Entah/RB kenapa/NN ini/DT bayik/NN suka/VBI banget/JJ :/: )/CP :/: )/CP :/: )/CP berenang/VBI di/IN Jln/NN Terusan/NNP Borobudur d/IN /NNP dan/NN di/IN Jalan/NN Perempatan/ADJ Malioboro/NNP"
`

Comment: Can a token be empty and classified as a noun? That is weird, but [`[^\s/]*/IN\b(?:(?![^\s/]*/IN\b).)+[^\s/]*/NNP\b`](https://regex101.com/r/S7PyAs/6) would cover that.

Comment: Also note that using `(?!\S+/IN\b).)+` for refusing of matching a string contain a particular sting is so inefficient by its own. No think what a monster would it be inside a repeated capture group :).

Comment: thanks @Kasramvd for the explanation. @wiktor-stribiżew in my case there will be no word only `/NNP` there must be a word in front of it. thanks by the way for the reference.

Comment: Yes that will cover it. But now you have [Two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Comment: Cool, use [`[^\s/]*/IN\b[^/]*(?:/(?!IN\b)[^/]*)*/NNP\b`](https://regex101.com/r/S7PyAs/7) if you want to speed it up.

Comment: @ytomo I see, this regex is clever and will cover almost all the cases (+), but note that in case you are dealing with larger data sets and need more performance it'd be a better idea to use a parser or go some other built-in functions.

Comment: @Kasramvd: You are free to post a non-regex solution. Why did you choose the regex in your deleted answer if you are so against a regex here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not against the regex I'm against the complicated regex. And if you were a pythonist you'd knew that `Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.` That's why I deleted that answer because right after I recognized the real problem I preferred  to not expand it.

Comment: I know that, I read it. But "beautiful" does not go hand in hand with regex if you need efficiency.

Comment: @ytomo: There is only one "complex" pattern in my solution: the `(?:(?!neg_lookahead).)+` [tempered greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat). When you unroll it, you will get [a more efficient, but uglier-looking regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384820/how-to-extract-some-words-pattern-from-string-using-regex-in-python/43384944?noredirect=1#comment73831971_43384944).